# setfacls and groups showing under Windows Advanced permissions

Tags: permissions, samba, chown

I'd love to find out what I am doing wrong here. I have a samba member server connected to a Windows AD environment sharing out a test folder. The end goal is to manage all permissions from windows as I would on a windows share, however provide access of the folders/files on the linux host.

I've been testing all day, it's mostly cracked I can add a Linux user but not a group.

Currently:

- I create the folder, chmod 777
- I setup the windows permissions on the share from windows as expected, which drops permissions down to to 770
- I can add a linux user by using setfacl -R -m u:testuser:rwx /share/testshare/, turned out this also happened when i did chown testuser /share/testshare and the user appears in the windows permissions editor
- I strip all the added linux root user/groups and everyone permissions
- Change this newly added testuser (Unix Group\testuser) to have the correct permissions and set for folder, subfolder and file access across the share

This works as expected, I have complete access from my windows groups and workstations, I can also log into the linux box and access the folders/files directly from the machine without permission problems.

However it would be great to get the group that encompasses this user in there instead testgroup (Unix group\testgroup) to provide further flexibility, much like I see root (Unix Group\root) prior to removing this.

I've tried setfacl -R -m g:testgroup:rwx /share/testshare/, however this didn't give visibility of the account in Windows to massage as appropriate. I've tried chown :testgroup /share/testshare but this also didn't make the group appear (Group owner when using getfacl shows the new group). In windows, i'd just be able to add the group directly, but this isn't the case.

I'm hoping someone has run across this before, any resources or advise would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but you haven't supplied enough info, what version of Samba and what is in your smb.conf . Without this data it is hard to see where you are going wrong, what I can tell you is that any permissions set on a Samba share from Windows are not shown by getfacl.